# How to load body background image after page loads(after load all site images) fully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to load body background image for my website. It is very large size so it takes long time to load my page. So I want to load body background image after getting page fully loaded.

I tried javascript `window.onload` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - remove the src attribute from the image first:

```
$(function() {
   $('img#bg').attr('src', 'images/myImage.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jQuery, you could do this (http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('large-background');
});
```

CSS:

```
.large-background {
    background: url('../img/large-image.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the body background at the end of the page in a style tag.

```
<style type='text/css'>body{background-image:url("/images/bgimage.gif")}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script for my carousel with Jquery:

1. Count all divs with class [classname]
2. Get each div data-src
3. Set for each div - style (background)

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var numBackground = $('.main-view-carosel').length /*amount of divs with 
      class*/
      console.log(numBackground);/*view the lenth*/

       setTimeout(function(){ /*set time out if needs to see ho it works*/

          for (let i = 0; i < numBackground; i++ ){ /*set the maximal [i] 
             amount of existing elements*/
             var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('main-view- 
             carosel');//get el with needed classname
             var requiredElement = elements[i]; /*get first one, second, third, 
             etc [i]*/
             var image = $(requiredElement).attr("data-src")/*get this div 
             data-src*/
             console.log(image);/*view in console this data-src*/
             requiredElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";/*set 
             background for current div*/
          }
       }, 100);
   });
   ```